# Gradient on svg <text> element is not working

Tags: html, css, svg, gradient, linear-gradients

I have an svg, inside of which I'm trying to add `<text>` element with gradient. The same `LinearGradient` works for one svg, but doesn't showing up for other svg. Does gradient can be applied to the `<text>` only if I have one nested element inside svg?

**What I'm trying to achieve**

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="55" viewBox="0 0 258 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <text font-size="30" x="0" y="30" fill="url(#paint5_linear_t)"> Text should be gradient like this</text>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="paint5_linear_t" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
      <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

**The same approach here, but it doesn't work**

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.card-banner-title {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="card" width="450" height="616" viewBox="0 0 450 616" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
    <rect x="61.7617" y="22.4829" width="380" height="548" rx="61" transform="rotate(5 61.7617 22.4829)" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"></rect>
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#filter1_b)">
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint1_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint2_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint3_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
  </g>
  <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="14" y="22" width="427" height="580">
    <rect x="61.7617" y="22.4829" width="380" height="548" rx="61" transform="rotate(5 61.7617 22.4829)" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"></rect>
  </mask>

  <text class="card-banner-title" fill="url(#paint5_linear_tc)" 
        data-svg-origin="0 -43" transform="matrix(0.9962,0.08716,-0.08716,0.9962,66.25212,409.8366)" 
        style="transform-origin: 0px 0px; transform: matrix(0.9962, 0.08716, -0.08716, 0.9962, 66.2521, 409.837);">Here is no gradient</text>
  
  <path d="M110.603 106.747L100.985 110.776L103.638 100.691L96.8337 92.7899L107.243 92.1965L112.656 83.2834L116.438 93.0009L126.587 95.3929L118.514 101.993L119.375 112.385L110.603 106.747Z" stroke="url(#paint7_radial)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
<defs>
  <filter id="filter0_b" x="-28" y="-19.5171" width="510.315" height="663.034" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="21"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"></feComposite>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"></feBlend>
  </filter>
  <filter id="filter1_b" x="-28" y="-19.5171" width="510.315" height="663.034" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="21"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"></feComposite>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"></feBlend>
  </filter>
  <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1.31579" height="1.31387">
    <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.00263158 0.00182482)"></use>
  </pattern>
  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="73.1617" y1="38.0857" x2="463.817" y2="606.864" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint1_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(114.681 86.3485) rotate(55.7067) scale(886.206 408.172)">
    <stop stop-color="white"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint2_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(251.762 296.483) rotate(58.5326) scale(410.938 284.945)">
    <stop stop-color="#48E6D8"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#48E6D8" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint3_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(414.27 42.5193) rotate(124.907) scale(676.798 469.762)">
    <stop stop-color="#002421"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.635417" stop-color="#002421" stop-opacity="0.364583"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#002421" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="73.1617" y1="38.0857" x2="463.817" y2="606.864" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="paint5_linear_tc" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing `gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"` from the gradient definition, as this tells it to use absolute units ([the default is `objectBoundingBox`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients#spreadmethod), which scales the gradient to fit the object):

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}

.card-banner-title {
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<svg class="card" width="450" height="616" viewBox="0 0 450 616" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g filter="url(#filter0_b)">
    <rect x="61.7617" y="22.4829" width="380" height="548" rx="61" transform="rotate(5 61.7617 22.4829)" fill="url(#paint0_linear)"></rect>
  </g>
  <g filter="url(#filter1_b)">
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint1_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint2_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
    <rect x="63.3525" y="24.3788" width="376.5" height="544.5" rx="59.25" transform="rotate(5 63.3525 24.3788)" stroke="url(#paint3_radial)" stroke-width="3.5"></rect>
  </g>
  <mask id="mask0" mask-type="alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="14" y="22" width="427" height="580">
    <rect x="61.7617" y="22.4829" width="380" height="548" rx="61" transform="rotate(5 61.7617 22.4829)" fill="url(#paint4_linear)"></rect>
  </mask>

  <text class="card-banner-title" fill="url(#paint5_linear_tc)" 
        data-svg-origin="0 -43" transform="matrix(0.9962,0.08716,-0.08716,0.9962,66.25212,409.8366)" 
        style="transform-origin: 0px 0px; transform: matrix(0.9962, 0.08716, -0.08716, 0.9962, 66.2521, 409.837);">Here is the gradient!</text>
  
  <path d="M110.603 106.747L100.985 110.776L103.638 100.691L96.8337 92.7899L107.243 92.1965L112.656 83.2834L116.438 93.0009L126.587 95.3929L118.514 101.993L119.375 112.385L110.603 106.747Z" stroke="url(#paint7_radial)" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
<defs>
  <filter id="filter0_b" x="-28" y="-19.5171" width="510.315" height="663.034" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="21"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"></feComposite>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"></feBlend>
  </filter>
  <filter id="filter1_b" x="-28" y="-19.5171" width="510.315" height="663.034" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
    <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"></feFlood>
    <feGaussianBlur in="BackgroundImage" stdDeviation="21"></feGaussianBlur>
    <feComposite in2="SourceAlpha" operator="in" result="effect1_backgroundBlur"></feComposite>
    <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="effect1_backgroundBlur" result="shape"></feBlend>
  </filter>
  <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1.31579" height="1.31387">
    <use xlink:href="#image0" transform="scale(0.00263158 0.00182482)"></use>
  </pattern>
  <linearGradient id="paint0_linear" x1="73.1617" y1="38.0857" x2="463.817" y2="606.864" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </linearGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint1_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(114.681 86.3485) rotate(55.7067) scale(886.206 408.172)">
    <stop stop-color="white"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint2_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(251.762 296.483) rotate(58.5326) scale(410.938 284.945)">
    <stop stop-color="#48E6D8"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#48E6D8" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <radialGradient id="paint3_radial" cx="0" cy="0" r="1" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" gradientTransform="translate(414.27 42.5193) rotate(124.907) scale(676.798 469.762)">
    <stop stop-color="#002421"></stop>
    <stop offset="0.635417" stop-color="#002421" stop-opacity="0.364583"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#002421" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
  </radialGradient>
  <linearGradient id="paint4_linear" x1="73.1617" y1="38.0857" x2="463.817" y2="606.864" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <stop stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.4"></stop>
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="paint5_linear_tc" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
    <stop offset="0%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,0,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
    <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(255,255,0);stop-opacity:1"></stop>
   </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 </svg>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you